.NET P/Invoke marshalling with spans instead of managed arrays
I have the following unmanaged function I need to call from C#:
    TLINError __stdcall LIN_GetAvailableHardware(
    HLINHW *pBuff,
    WORD wBuffSize,
    int *pCount
    );

The library provides this C# P/Invoke definition:
[DllImport("plinapi.dll", EntryPoint = "LIN_GetAvailableHardware")]
public static extern TLINError GetAvailableHardware(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]
    HLINHW[] pBuff,
    ushort wBuffSize,
    out ushort pCount);

This function receives a C like array with its size defined via wBuffSize. pCount is the actual count of items written into the array. HLINHW is an alias for ushort. I was wondering if I could somehow avoid the allocation of a managed array. My first intuition was to modify the C# function definition to accept a Span<ushort> and pass a stack allocated span as parameter.
[DllImport("plinapi.dll", EntryPoint = "LIN_GetAvailableHardware")]
public static extern TLINError GetAvailableHardware(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]
    Span<HLINHW> pBuff,
    ushort wBuffSize,
    out ushort pCount);

This failed with the following error: Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Generic types cannot be marshaled
I can workaround it by changing the definition to:
[DllImport("plinapi.dll", EntryPoint = "LIN_GetAvailableHardware")]
public static extern TLINError GetAvailableHardware(
    ref readonly HLINHW pBuff,
    ushort wBuffSize,
    out ushort pCount);

And call it like this:
ReadOnlySpan<ushort> buffer = stackalloc ushort[availableHardwareCount];
status = PLinApi.GetAvailableHardware(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(buffer), (ushort)(buffer.Length*sizeof(ushort)), out availableHardwareCount);

Is it possible to define the C# P/Invoke definition in such a way that it would accept a span directly? If so how can I do it? There should also still be a possibility to pass null into the unmanaged function.
If we ignore the slight inconvenience of calling MemoryMarshal.GetReference(buffer) would such direct span P/Invoke benefit the resulting program in any way. Performance, Memory?

You could try benchmarking each way to see A) if it's possible, and B) whether there are any performance improvements or reductions in the amount of memory consumed.

This native function requires an array, you have to provide one.  No point in trying to optimize it, ushort[] is a blittable type so the pinvoke marshaller simply pins the array and lets the native code is directly write into the managed array.  Can't do better than that.

@phuzi I did try the two ways I listed. I am not experienced enough with P/Invoke to come up with other ways I could test. That is precisely why I am asking. If there is a way that works I can then benchmark.

@HansPassant It requires a c style array which is essentially a pointer. If that pointer points to a managed array or a stack allocated one wouldn't make much difference. Other than not producing garbage that needs to be collected.

I have figured it out. There appears to be a new source generated P/Invoke option since .NET 7. It replaces DllImport. If we now define the P/Invoke function like following:
[LibraryImport("plinapi.dll", EntryPoint = "LIN_GetAvailableHardware")]
public static partial TLINError GetAvailableHardware(
    ReadOnlySpan<HLINHW> pBuff,
    ushort wBuffSize,
    out ushort pCount);

We can call it simply with:
ReadOnlySpan<ushort> buffer = stackalloc ushort[availableHardwareCount];
PLinApi.GetAvailableHardware(buffer, (ushort)(buffer.Length*sizeof(ushort)), 
out availableHardwareCount);

Or the null version:
PLinApi.GetAvailableHardware(ReadOnlySpan<ushort>.Empty, 0, 
out var availableHardwareCount);

It works with zero allocations at the managed side.
